# Chrome Cookies Aren't Being Stored In The Chrome Cookies File

Tags: python, sqlite, authentication, google-chrome, cookies

So essentially I've been looking into how Chrome and all web browsers store their cookies. I've discoverd of course that Chrome's system works as follows:

All Chrome files are stored in: %USERPROFILE%/AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data
There are multiple profiles named in the following way: If no profiles are made there is one called "Default" otherwise they go in the following pattern: "Profile 1", "Profile 2", etc...
Each profile has it's unique folder which stores all the information: Cache, Login info, and of course COOKIES
The login info is stored in a file called Login Data, Cache in \Cache\Cache_Data, Cookies in \Network\Cookies. Login Data + Cookies are both in sqlite3 format.

The problem is that when I take a random site for example, minecraft.net. It has a lot of cookies. But when I look at the Cookies file in a browser, there is only one cookie for it. Why is this. I was checking a week ago helping fix something with my brother roblox account and I found a similar thing. I noticed that there was a cookie called .RBLXSECURITY that had his token in it but when I looked in his cookies it wasn't there. I then found a file in the roblox appdata that stored the token. So does chrome access token from files and if so is there a way to get access to them aswell?

I've tried looking up stuff for this but I couldn't find anything. I also tried looking through a lot of my files but nothing there either.